# Accessing data on Microsoft SQL Server from a PostgreSQL function

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, plpgsql, cross-database, plperl

I have an application that uses PostgreSQL but also interacts with a third-party-controlled database on MSSQL.  The data are sometimes tied together closely enough that it becomes desirable to do things like:

```
select thing_from_pg, thing_from_ms_crossover_function(thing_from_pg) -- etc
```

Currently I implement `thing_from_ms_crossover_function` in plperl.  Is there a way to do this in plpgsql or something, so that I don't need to start a plperl interpreter for such cases?

Another option is obviously to access both databases from my client app, but that becomes far less convenient than the view syntax above.

Comment: Did you have a look at the dblink module? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html

Comment: Sounded promising, but it only supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases.

Comment: Ah, right. I always forget that. If you are adventorous you might want to try a foreign data wrapper (odbc_fdw or jdbc_fdw): http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers

Comment: Aha, sounds good.  They link specifically to this article http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/249-ODBC-Foreign-Data-wrapper-to-query-SQL-Server-on-Window---Part-2.html from there, right on!

Comment: Although, doesn't seem production-ready by the sounds of the article.

Comment: That's why I said "*adventurous*" ;)

Comment: Right.  Apparently I skimmed over that word.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options, well three basic ones rather.

The first is to use `DBI-Link` and then access this via your pl/pgsql or pl/perl function.  The nice thing about `DBI-Link` is that it is relatively older and mature.  If it works for you I would start there.

The second option is to use foreign data wrappers.

The third option is to write a more general framework in something like `pl/perl` that you can call from `pl/pgsql`.  However at that point you are basically looking at re-inventing DBI-Link so I think you are better off starting with DBI-Link and modifying it as needed.